# angular ng-repeat function app function not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a created an angular repeat function. which loop my `section` container. so ultimately this repeat function will loop content within the `section` tag.

Unfortunately I am getting a console error, which is saying `app function not defined` I am not 100% sure why this is happening when I have defined `app` in body. which looks like the following `body ng-app="app"` I have uploaded my code [click here](http://plnkr.co/edit/BkO0zj7BKoNDPeOajGWt?p=preview)

I am assuming my html structure is correct, however I not 100% sure about my js.

```
   app.controller("GamesViewEntries", function ($scope){
          $scope.gamesViewItem =  { name: "tom", sex: "male" }
      });
```

Can someone guide me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to declare the `app` variable by bootstrapping your app. That error message was saying that the variable `app` wasn't declared, not that you never included an `ng-app`

```
var app = angular.module("app", [])
```

You're `ng-repeat` is also targeting the controller name, and not your scope object, change it to:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in gamesViewItem" class="box">
```

And since you only have an object, not an array of objects, use the `(k, v) in object` syntax.

Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/nQw0L7CEBpV5zDHTM97l?p=preview

Comment: before or after the function?  var app = angular.module("app", []);
        app.controller("GamesViewEntries", function ($scope){
              $scope.gamesViewItem =  { name: "tom", sex: "male" }
          });
     doesn't work for me. would you able to demonstrate it on plunker?

Comment: Before, it's not working because your `ng-repeat` is expecting an array of objects, not just an object.

Comment: awesome this (key,value) is new to me, cam this be found on the angular site or is it a hack?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a module in angular.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
```

The name `myApp` which is the first argument in the `angular.module` function corresponds to the app name in your template. `<div ng-app="myApp"></div>`